# Render adminthtml block after ajax post success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have a custom extension and i am working on functionality enhancement.
i have a custom grid and when i click on edit some part of the form comes from.

```
Hello/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Edit/Field/Items.php
```

from the items.php i am sending ajax request to adminhtml controller function and implementing something there. now i want to render that items.php block onsuccess of ajax post.

I used this in controller after implementing things in database.

```
$table= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_field_item');

        $response['itemstable'] = $table;
        return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

When i tried to get that in onsuccess of ajax

```
 var json = response.responseText.evalJSON(true);
alert(json.itemstable);
```

it shows nothing

Please help

Comment: `alert(response)` looks like what?

Comment: What is `evalJSON()`? This isn't a js/jQuery method but Prototype one so are you including it? BTW, what about your ajax request code? Why don't you just set as `dataType` json to avoid any manual parsing? And what about error in console???

Comment: itemstable:false @A.Wolff

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the second line to

```
$response['itemstable'] = $table->_toHtml();
```

otherwise you won't get the html output of the created block.

Comment: No it's just showing js code which i used in my block no table html